# Handling exceptions during localizing in .net5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, asp.net-core-localization

I would like to ask you if it is possible to handle exception during localizing? For instance I have made recently mistake in my resx file, and my localizer caused that in one language users got error (in translated version I wrote something like "foo {2} bar" instead of "foo {0} bar". I would like to handle this exception that localizer returns the "not translated" string.

Is it possible to write some kind of special exception handler for localizer? Should it implements any interface or something?

Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to custom a Resource filters with `OnResourceExecuted()`.

> **Filter types**

Each filter type is executed at a different stage in the filter pipeline:

- Authorization filters

run first and are used to determine whether the user is authorized for the request. Authorization filters short-circuit the pipeline if the request is not authorized.

- Resource filters

Run after authorization.
`OnResourceExecuting` runs code before the rest of the filter pipeline. For example, `OnResourceExecuting` runs code before model binding.
`OnResourceExecuted` runs code after the rest of the pipeline has completed.

- Action filters

Run code immediately before and after an action method is called.
 Can change the arguments passed into an action. Can change the result    returned from the action. 
Are not supported in Razor Pages.

- Exception filters

apply global policies to unhandled exceptions that occur    before the response body has been written to.

- Result filters

run code immediately before and after the execution of action results. They run only when the action method has executed successfully. They are useful for logic that must surround view or formatter execution.

[The following diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) shows how filter types interact in the filter pipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i use a simpler way without any middle ware ,i translate the exception messages into localized string as below ,

call the method in your catch with the original exception message
catch (Exception dex)

```
    {

        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = Models.SiteUtils.FriendlyErrorMessage(dex) });
    }
```

method for localization of error messages ,will search for the exception message and get your version of it ,
notice i use Message.Contains(x.OriginalError) so i do not need to translate he whole message exactly ,you may decide to use exact match if you need based on your own logic

```
 public static string FriendlyErrorMessage(Exception dex)
        {
            var Message = dex.Message;
            var listOfStrings = new tblErrorMsgMappingVM().GetAll().ToList();


            var ErrorMessage = listOfStrings.Find(x => Message.Contains(x.OriginalError));

            if (ErrorMessage != null)
            {
                Message = ErrorMessage.ErrorMessage;

            }
            else
                Message = "Unknown Error ,pelase review the log";
           
            var value = new tblLocalizationRecordsVM().GetResourceValue(Message, "ErrorMsg");
            return value;
        }
```